# Connecting Apps Script to SQL Server with JDBC in G Suite

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I'm trying to make the most basic JDBC connection to MS SQL Server from Google Apps Script (Sheets) to read simple data. I am working within an enterprise G Suite environment so nothing is external as far as IP's go. I have not found much online about doing this from within a G Suite environment where the actual enterprise server IP is likely not in those ranges listed as those needing to be whitelisted.

`var connectionString = 'jdbc:sqlserver://myServerName:1433/myDatabaseName;';`

`var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(connectionString,'myUsername', 'myPassword');`

The error I'm getting on the `getConnection` line is:

> Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.

I've verified I can ping the server on the correct port. But I suspect that is a moot point since the connection request is coming from the G Suite server and not my machine.

I'm trying to get SQL Server audit privileges so that I can take a look at any failed logins on the SQL Server.

Eventually, I also need to do the same with an Oracle server. I've run the same test with the Oracle creds and slightly different connection string which results in the exact same error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're connecting to an external database, MSSQL (Microsoft SQL) or Oracle in this case, you'll need to white-list the following IP address ranges in your database settings in order for Apps Script's JDBC connector to access it:

```js
64.18.0.0 - 64.18.15.255
64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255
66.102.0.0 - 66.102.15.255
66.249.80.0 - 66.249.95.255
72.14.192.0 - 72.14.255.255
74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255
173.194.0.0 - 173.194.255.255
207.126.144.0 - 207.126.159.255
209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255
216.239.32.0 - 216.239.63.255
```

Whether or not you have a GSuite enterprise account doesn't matter, the database you want to connect to is external.

[See official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#creating_other_database_connections).